# Display Custom Post if custom field is marked

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, featured-post

I'm trying to get a custom post to show up on the front page only if a custom field I made is marked, otherwise it sould look for the one that is (and only one, not all marked).

I currently have this:

```
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'courses', 'posts_per_page' => 1 );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

            $marked= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'feature-it', true);
            if ($marked) {
                echo "<h3>";
                  the_title();
                  get_the_post_thumbnail();
                echo "</h3>";
            }
            endwhile;
```

It is kinda working, but if the latest post is not marked to show, it doesn't show anything, as opposed to showing the previous marked one.

Can anyone tip me on how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it will not return any posts if your first post does not have custom field `feature-it`. Because you are checking for custom field after you are running your query.

So let me explain what exactly you are doing in your query. You are asking WordPress to return one post with `post_type` `courses`. And WordPress will return only 1 post regardless of custom field. After that you are asking WordPress to check for custom field `feature-it` and if this post have custom field then it will print title and thumbnail. If post does not have custom field then it will not print anything.

You are suppose to get one post with `post_type` `courses` which have a custom field `feature-it`. So you will need to check it within you query. This is how it should be checking for custom field within [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'courses',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'feature-it'
        )
    )
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        echo "<h3>";
            the_title();
            get_the_post_thumbnail();
        echo "</h3>";

    endwhile;

endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Glad I could help you on this. :)